# Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedMillis()J while reading file in spark?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is spark application to read the input json.
But I'm not able to read the input file.

```
public class SampleApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        SparkConf conf= new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]");

        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();

        // Encoders are created for Java bean class
        Encoder<Input> inputEncoder = Encoders.bean(Input.class);
        Dataset<Input> df  = spark.read().option("multiline","true").json(args[0]).as(inputEncoder);

        System.out.println("Finished !!!!!");

        df.show();

        spark.close();
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies I included in the project:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'


    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.9'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.9.9'

    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.elapsedMillis()J
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:279)
    at org.apache.spark.input.StreamFileInputFormat.setMinPartitions(PortableDataStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.BinaryFileRDD.getPartitions(BinaryFileRDD.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
    .....
```

I did run with gradle dependencies.
I couldn't paste everything

```
  +--- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:2.3.0
|    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.8 (*)
|    |    +--- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.4 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.0.8
|    |    |    \--- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.0.8
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:3.0.8
|    |    +--- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:4.7
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |    \--- org.spark-project.spark:unused:1.0.0
|    +--- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.orc:orc-core:1.4.1
|    |    +--- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
|    |    +--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
|    |    +--- io.airlift:aircompressor:0.8
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.25
|    +--- org.apache.orc:orc-mapreduce:1.4.1
|    |    +--- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:3.0.3 (*)
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4 -> 1.10
|    |    \--- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.6.4 -> 2.6.5 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:1.8.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:1.8.2
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.25
|    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:1.8.2
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:1.8.2 (*)
|    |    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5 -> 1.10
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.5 -> 1.10
|    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:1.8.2
|    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:1.8.2 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:2.3.1
|    |    +--- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:1.8.2
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11 -> 1.9.13 (*)
|    |    +--- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.11 -> 1.9.13
|    |    \--- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.1.6 -> 1.1.2.6
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.7.1 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.arrow:arrow-vector:0.8.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.arrow:arrow-format:0.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.vlkan:flatbuffers:1.2.0-3f79e055
|    |    +--- org.apache.arrow:arrow-memory:0.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    |    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.9 -> 2.9.9
|    |    +--- com.carrotsearch:hppc:0.7.2
|    |    +--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
|    |    +--- com.vlkan:flatbuffers:1.2.0-3f79e055
|    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
|    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25
|    +--- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm5-shaded:4.4
|    \--- org.spark-project.spark:unused:1.0.0
+--- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0 (*)
\--- junit:junit:4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
```

Issues:

1. I think I'm missing dependencies or there is conflict between the dependencies
2. How to get the input class from Dataset

Comment: can you add in description, the result of  mvn dependency:tree

Comment: or gradle app:dependencies

Comment: @Jacob I added in the description

Comment: use this please: gradle dependencies

Comment: @Jacob Updated the desciption

Comment: can add this in your gradle dependency :
compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: 'r05'

Comment: It's not working @Jacob

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat this is the error I'm getting now @Jacob

Comment: you have a problem with dependency, add this: compile group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-common', version: '2.7.2'

Comment: I added this :  compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:2.7.2') {force = true}
  compile('org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.7.2') {force = true}  .. No error but I can't see output.

Comment: [444 [Executor task launch worker for task 1] INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD  - Reading File path: file:///SampleInput.json, range: 0-179, partition values: [empty row]

Comment: === Result of Batch Resolution ===
!'DeserializeToObject unresolveddeserializer(initializejavabean(newInstance(class Input), ...  What is it about? @Jacob

Answer (score 0):

Method `elapsedMillis()` was deleted long time ago. Seems like you need update some of your libraries or use old guava version.

In order to get a dependency tree run `gradle dependencies`.

Comment: I'm not using guava at all @Kirill

Comment: But where did ```com.google.common.base.Stopwatch``` came from in that case?

Comment: org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.3.0
 -> +--- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.6.5
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.6.5
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:2.6.5
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:11.0.2 -> 16.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Include the following dependencies to maven. That should resolve the problem.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>failureaccess</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>listenablefuture</artifactId>
            <version>9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
            <artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
            <version>1.2_jdk5</version>
        </dependency>
```